# How do I develop a Ubuntu application using the Go language?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, golang

I want to develop some application for the Ubuntu platform. But I don't know C++. I can learn QML very easily. The problem is that the logic or process behind the scene in an application seems to use C++. So I thought maybe I should learn [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) (another reasons are also there), because it is not as vast as C++, and it can be [directly used](https://github.com/go-qml/qml) in QML.

I want to use the standard Ubuntu SDK API in my application. How can I do that using Go? How do I proceed?

Comment: For anyone who found this question via here, checkout this G+ thread [https://plus.google.com/+RahulSinha58/posts/7qdqE5peh1X] it has a few suggestions/answers.

Comment: Correct Link https://plus.google.com/+RahulSinha58/posts/7qdqE5peh1X

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly can: Here's a template with a short tutorial:  https://github.com/nikwen/ubuntu-go-qml-template

Or if you want to create scopes, check out: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/tutorials/developing-scopes-go/